# How does one fit conditional Poisson regression in SAS?

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, sas, matching

I'm interested in fitting a conditional Poisson regression model using PROC GENMOD in SAS to analyze a matched cohort study. However, it's not quite clear to me how I should exactly go about it.

My impression is that a REPEATED statement should be used along with the events/trials syntax, but if so then how does one account for continuous covariates in the model, such as age?

I would be most grateful if anyone had any pointers. Thus far, Google and the internet have disappointed me. Cheers.

Comment: Is this the same as zero inflated Poisson regression or no?

Comment: Probably not, try searching for conditional logistic regression in SAS. There should be info on that, and then I don't think it would be too hard to modify it for Poisson regression.

In addition to GENMOD there is a new procedure called COUNTREG that handles categorical outcomes (of course GLIMMIX does too).

Comment: Why don't you use Genmod with Poisson distribution and repeated subject=match_id ?

Comment: Hi @Tiffany, could you give a little bit more explanation in your answer? Also, the OP seemed to wonder how to include covariates in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a paper from from NESUG that goes through the use of both GENMOD and PHREG for matched cohort data: http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug07/sa/sa01.pdf

It appears in this paper that continuous covariates are included in their standard form in PHREG, and somewhat suggests that including them in GENMOD will be difficult, if not impossible. But that should provide a decent starting point. If you *cannot* use a Cox proportional hazard model and need a poisson estimate, you might be able to use something like a propensity-score or inverse-probability-of-treatment weights to address your confounding before the data ever hits a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use genmod but you will have to restructure your dataset. This paper gives a quite detailed on how to do conditional poission in SAS.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/84f5/55569662b8c4882b213cd13f75622eaf495e.pdf